# Передача параметров в python скрипт

Tags: python, bash

Как можно передать в скрипт на питоне результат выполнения определенной команды в ОС?

Пример: в bash выполнить команду mailq и её вывод передать в скрипт, как аргумент, чтобы можно было, например, отправить в письме.

Основная цель использования python в том, чтобы мониторить определенные метрики на уровне ОС и затем отрабатывать определенный алгоритм действий (оповещение, решение ситуации и т.д.). Но мои познания не настолько велики, чтобы все необходимые метрики запрашивать из скрипта, пришлось немного костылей использовать.

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, Ваш вопрос. Например, если команда: `еcho abc`, то что Вы хотите с ней сделать? Вызвать из Питона и прочитать её вывод?

Comment: в этом случае используйте первый пример в [ответе @alexander barakin](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/453031/23044). В общем случае информацию необходимую для ответа помещайте прямо в вопрос, то есть не нужно её ввиде комментария оставлять к вопросу (нажмите кнопку "править" по вопросом).

Comment: @jfs, можно писать так: `"нажмите кнопку [edit]"`, что преобразуется в: "нажмите кнопку [edit]".

Comment: Andrey, я дополнил ответ примером упрощённого решения вашего примера.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если под результатом подразумевается то, что «определённая команда» выводит в *stdout*, то, например, так:

```
$ определённая.команда её.параметры | скрипт.на.питоне его.параметры
```

---

если же под результатом подразумеватеся код возврата, то, например, так:

```
$ определённая.команда её.параметры; echo $? | скрипт.на.питоне его.параметры
```

---

в самом «скрипте на питоне» следует просто прочитать *stdin*.

---

> Пример: в bash выполнить команду mailq и её вывод передать в скрипт, как агрумент, чтобы можно было, например, отправить в письме.

*python* в приведённом примере будет, вероятно, чрезмерным усложнением (если почтовая система нормально настроена):

```
 $ sudo mailq | mail -s "mail queue at $(date)" dedushke@derevnju.na
```